# Subquery to get maximum value in LINQ query in C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I'm trying to create a sub-query to obtain the latest date from a table, unrelated to the rest of the query.

My query is below.  I'd like to select the highest date in a sub-table as a value and project it to my model below.

My *other* tabe is **Feedback** and contains a date value and a username field

```
return (from t1 in db.TaskAppointmentOpens

                from t2 in db.Tasks.Where(t => (t.Task_ID == t1.Parent_Task_ID))

                from t3 in db.UserNames.Where(t => (t.User_Username == t2.OwnerTypeItem_ID))

                where ((t2.Item_ID > 0) && (t2.Type_ID > 0) && (t2.Creator == user) && (t1.AppointmentEnd < DateTime.Now) && (t1.AppointmentStart > EntityFunctions.AddMonths(DateTime.Now, -6)) && (from i in db.AppointmentFeedbacks where i.AppointmentId == t1.ID select i).Count() == 0)

                group new {t2, t3} by new { 
                  t2.OwnerTypeItem_ID, t3.Name
                } into g

                let oldestAppointment = g.Min(uh => uh.t2.Due_Date)

                    select new TelesalesNeglectedFeedbackModel
                    {
                        UserFullName = g.Key.Name,
                        QtyOutstanding = g.Select(x => x.t2.Task_ID).Distinct().Count(),
                        OldestAppointment = oldestAppointment
                        LastDateInOtherTable = HERE <======
                    }).Take(5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the table and field this way:

```
LastDateInOtherTable = db.Feedback.Max(f => f.Date)
```

Or use a `let` clause as you've done for the other column and then assign it later:

```
let lastDate = db.Feedback.Max(f => f.Date)
...
LastDateInOtherTable = lastDate
```